# How can we get the source IP of who is connecting to Tridion coreservices

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service

We are facing few issues with our Tridion CMS which continuously reports

> Insufficient winsock resources available to complete socket connection initiation

In the event viewer we receive the below error message
[image]

The user is no longer present and we have deleted from tridion and now we are not sure from which application , the core service request is made to cms.

Comment: There might be some additional network monitoring and logging on the CM server. Check what Windows Server has for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable WCF Tracing in the Core Service's config file (`TcmServiceHost.exe.config` or `web.config` depending on the Core Service endpoints which are used).

These config files contain comments explaining how to enable WCF tracing and how to read the trace files.

However, the event log message clearly shows that the problem occurs in the SDL Web Batch Processor service (which processes batches which are typically created when a user performs an action on multiple items in the CME).

The batch processor service impersonates the user who created the batch. It also performs some actions using a sysadmin account which is configured in `Tridion.ContentManager.config`.

Comment: Thanks Rick for the suggestion of enabling wcf tracing.yes the error describes information about the batch processing which is failing because of the deleted tridion user who is performing some multiple operations via core services . We are not sure on which machine this piece of code is invoking or scheduled so that we can remove it or modify it to use some existing impersonation account. We want to know the host server details which is causing this issue. Hope enabling the wcf tracing can help